# Get a const value back on a screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've a component called `IndividualInfoCard` which is implemented as:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [passportNRIC, setPassportNRIC] = useState('')
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('')
    const [dob, setDOB] = useState('')

    var noOfIndSelected = noOfInd;

    const individualDetails = {
        fullName: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phoneNumber,
        passportNRIC: passportNRIC,
        dob: dob
    }

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>Individual {noOfIndSelected}</Text>
            <TextInput placeholder={'Enter Full Name *'} value={name} onChangeText={setName} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
            <TextInput placeholder={'Enter Email *'} value={email} onChangeText={setEmail} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
            <TextInput placeholder={'Enter Passport or NRIC Number *'} value={passportNRIC} onChangeText={setPassportNRIC} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
            <TextInput placeholder={'Phone Number *'} value={phoneNumber} onChangeText={setPhoneNumber} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
            <TextInput placeholder={'Date of Birth *'} value={dob} onChangeText={setDOB} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
  </View>
);
```

I'm implementing a logic where I am adding `IndividualInfoCard` component via a loop from a class named as `IndividualDetails .js`:

```
let indCards = [];
for (let index = 0; index < totalIndividuals; index++) {
  indCards.push(<IndividualInfoCard noOfInd={index + 1} key={index} />);
}
```

In this class, I have a button that takes the user to the next screen but before proceeding to the next screen I want to access `individualDetails` which is the `const` in `IndividualInfoCard` component.

```
<MainActionButton title={'Continue'} pressEvent={() => {
    indCards.forEach(indiv => {
       alert(HOW_TO_GET_SAY_EMAIL_HERE)
    });
}} />
```

So how do I get `HOW_TO_GET_SAY_EMAIL_HERE`? If I do `indiv.detailsComp.email` I get

> undefined is not an object

Comment: You can maintain the state in the parent component rather than in `IndividualInfoCard` and pass the value, change handlers as props.

Comment: The `IndividualInfoCard` is being rendered multiple times on the parent screen, so it's like a similar composition but a different key. So, handling it from the parent class would require say 5 (no. of fields in the form) * 3 (total forms) = 15 values?

Comment: Yeah, you can have an array of objects as your state.

Comment: @RameshReddy can you put this in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `ref`.

In your `IndividualInfoCard.js`, you have to do this.

```
import { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react';

function IndividualInfoCard (props, ref) {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [passportNRIC, setPassportNRIC] = useState('')
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('')
    const [dob, setDOB] = useState('')

    var noOfIndSelected = noOfInd;

    const individualDetails = {
        fullName: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phoneNumber,
        passportNRIC: passportNRIC,
        dob: dob
    }

    const getIndividualDetails = () => { return individualDetails }

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ getIndividualDetails }));

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Individual {noOfIndSelected}</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder={'Enter Full Name *'} value={name} onChangeText={setName} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
        <TextInput placeholder={'Enter Email *'} value={email} onChangeText={setEmail} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
        <TextInput placeholder={'Enter Passport or NRIC Number *'} value={passportNRIC} onChangeText={setPassportNRIC} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
        <TextInput placeholder={'Phone Number *'} value={phoneNumber} onChangeText={setPhoneNumber} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
        <TextInput placeholder={'Date of Birth *'} value={dob} onChangeText={setDOB} style={styles.textField} editable={true} />
    </View>
    );
}

export default forwardRef(IndividualInfoCard);
```

Then, in your `IndividualDetails.js`, you need to create `ref`s for each and every card.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

var individualInfoCardRefs = [];
var indCards = [];

for (let index = 0; index < totalIndividuals; index++) {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  individualInfoCardRefs.push(ref); 
  indCards.push(<IndividualInfoCard ref={ref} noOfInd={index + 1} key={index} />);
}
```

Finally, you can access the data through the `ref`.

```
<MainActionButton title={'Continue'} pressEvent={() => {
    indCards.forEach(indiv, index => {
       const individualDetails = individualInfoCardRefs[index].current.getIndividualDetails();
       const { fullName, email, phone, passportNRIC, dob } = individualDetails

       // do whatever you want now...
    });
}} />
```

Comment: There is an error that reads `totalIndiviuals.map is not a function` and I think it's on this line `const individualInfoCardRefs = totalIndividuals.map(() => useRef(null));`

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha I edited my answer. Please try in that way and let me know.